# The Reason of using LinkedHashMap for Jwts.claim()

Tags: jjwt

For my personal project, I used jjwt library for authentication procedure with token.

And I got some problems with making jwt tokens under multi-threaded environment. So, I checked source code of Claims class and found it uses LinkedHashMap for saving data .

My question is "Why doesn't Claims class use ConcurrentHashMap instead of LinkedHashMap?".

Is there any optional setting for using jjwt library under multi-threaded environment?

Or Is there any reason that they use LinkedHashMap for saving data? (Maybe for performance issue or generalization for various case)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.